# Custom UITableViewCell view disappears autoligned to right

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Been banging at this for a couple of days now off and on.  The issue is that when I use autolayout constraints and align a view on the right edge of a UITableViewCell, the view disappears.  Below is code that reproduces the issue, but I've tried lots of other things like various "needsLayout", "needsUpdateContraints", etc. in various places along with their respective "updateLayoutIfNeeded" calls all over the place.  I have also tried overriding "updateConstraints" and adding the constraints there.  But I get the exact same results no matter what I do.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 2;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString* SimpleIdentifier=@"Simple";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleIdentifier];
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;

    UILabel* label1;
    UILabel* label2;

    if(cell==nil){
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleIdentifier];

        label1=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
        label1.tag=100;
        label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];

        label2=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 50)];
        label2.tag=101;
        label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label2];

        NSDictionary* viewsDictionary=@{@"label1":label1,@"label2":label2};
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[label1]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[label2]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
        //[cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[label1]-[label2]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
    } else {
        label1=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
        label1=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
    }

    label1.text=@"Label 1";
    label2.text=@"Label 2";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Auto layout issues are tricky. I see someone has posted an answer but, in general, you need to use the view debugger to look at the constraints at runtime. This will show you graphically what you are doing wrong and is a better approach than randomly trying code in different methods. In WWDC 2015, there were also two videos (#218 and #219 Mysteries of AutoLayout Part 1 & 2) which take you through debugging Autolayout issues. These can be downloaded for free from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/

Comment: Thanks, it did turn out to be something stupid simple (see comment below).  I'll check out those videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString* SimpleIdentifier=@"Simple";
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleIdentifier];

UILabel* label1;
UILabel* label2;

if(cell==nil){
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleIdentifier];

    label1=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
    label1.tag=100;
    label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];

    label2=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 50)];
    label2.tag=101;
    label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label2];

    NSDictionary* viewsDictionary=@{@"label1":label1,@"label2":label2};
    [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[label1]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
    [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[label2]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
    [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[label1]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
      [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[label2]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];

} else {
    label1=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    label1=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
}

label1.text=@"Label 1";
label2.text=@"Label 2";

return cell;
```

}

And screenshot
[image]

Comment: From the looks of it, you added two vertical constraints.  That did not solve my problem, but knowing it worked for you from the screenshot did help a lot.  Turns out (forehead slap) I had no auto layout constraints on my UITableView, and the actual table was running off the side of the screen.  It works with, and without your recommended changes.  Kudos for the screenshot, that's what keyed me in to look for something other than in my code.